# How can I get the value of data- attributes using Web::Scraper?

Tags: perl

I've been able to scrape data from websites with a simple HTML structure and retrieve data from various tags using the Perl module [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper). However, I came across a `data-` attribute which I'm unable to process in the usual way.

The tag is:

```
<img class="slide_image"
     src="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/computerassistedsurgery-160629113952/95/computer-assisted-surgery-1-638.jpg?cb=1467200461" 
     data-small="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/computerassistedsurgery-160629113952/85/computer-assisted-surgery-1-320.jpg?cb=1467200461" 
     data-normal="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/computerassistedsurgery-160629113952/95/computer-assisted-surgery-1-638.jpg?cb=1467200461" 
     data-full="https://image.slidesharecdn.com/computerassistedsurgery-160629113952/95/computer-assisted-surgery-1-1024.jpg?cb=1467200461" 
     alt="COMPUTER ASSISTED SURGERY Something ">
```

The part I need is `"https://image.slidesharecdn.com/computerassistedsurgery-160629113952/95/computer-assisted-surgery-1-1024.jpg?cb=1467200461"` that comes after the attribute `data-full`. My current code is:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib "lib";

use URI;
use Web::Scraper;
use YAML;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use URI::Encode;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $purlToScrape='https://www.slideshare.net/drdeepashivnani/computer-assisted-surgery?from_m_app=android';

print "Scraping $purlToScrape\n";

my $noticescr = scraper {
  process 'section>img', 'link[]' => 'TEXT'; 
};

my $notices = $noticescr->scrape(URI->new($purlToScrape));

print Dumper($notices);
```

This fails with the error:

> Don't know what to do with 0 => undef at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Web/Scraper.pm line 150.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Those are attributes, not tags.

Comment: Right. Forgive the typo.

Comment: You loaded a lot of things that you don't need.

Comment: That's because it's part of a larger script which needs those. For my question, the big script seems redundant.

Comment: I don't have a computer right now. The problem is the TEXT. You need the attribute there.

Comment: How should I modify it?

Comment: Yes, I am using the process method. I just dont know how to use the data- attribute here.

Comment: You forgot to put quotes around `link[]`. Is that a transcription error or is that your actual code?

Comment: Even if you use more things, why do you need LWP and Mechanize? Mech is a subclass of LWP. Looks strange.

Comment: @simbabque One of the hazards of reusing code from one of my many scripts..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TEXT` is for getting the text inside an element. Use `@attr` to get the value of an attribute:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Web::Scraper;

my $scraper = scraper {
    process 'img', 'links[]' => '@data-foo';
};

my $result = $scraper->scrape('<img data-foo="foo" data-bar="bar">');
say for @{ $result->{links} };
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: Also `links[]` needed to be inside quotes. I think this OP added `use strict` only in the version he has published, as it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Borodin Even without strict, that's a syntax error, so I assume they copy-pasted wrong.